# Cannot add custom font to Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uifont, custom-font

OK, so I've done a lot of reading, followed several tutorials, and I still cannot add a custom font to my iOS app.

I've (1) added and copied the fonts to xcode.[image]

I've (2) added them to the correct target.[image]

I've (3) made sure they are included as resources in the bundle.[image]

I've (4) included them in my info.plist.[image]

I've (5) tried to find them in my list of fonts by inserting this code.[image]

Yet the fonts STILL do not appear. I recognize that the font name is not the same as the file name, but I compared the list of font family names and font names from before and after, and they are the exact same, proving no fonts were added. I've followed SO and these tutorials to a T but nothing is working.

Comment: You are editing the wrong info.plist file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You inadvertently added them to the wrong (Test) Info.plist.